# How to hide user accounts when starting up my Mac?

Tags: terminal, user-account

[image]
I would like to hide that Admin user. Command: `sudo dscl . create /Users/admin IsHidden 1` only hides the user when logging out. But when I restart my computer and the launch screen pops up I can still see the user. Are there any more commands for launch screens? What should I do? Is it even possible?

Comment: That looks like the FileVault login, not the normal login screen. `IsHidden` only hides from the login screen, but leaves users on the FileVault login so that they are still able to unlock the disk. Do you have FileVault enabled?

Comment: @grgarside yes I have FileVault enabled. Is there a way to hide it without disabling FileVault?